# Drupal: Duplicate entry '' for key 2 query:

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, insert, mysql-error-1062

I have a script that is programatically creating users on the fly to sync with an old database.  It's been puring along quite nicely for a while.  Now all of the sudden It started erroring out with a duplicate key error when trying to insert a user.  the exact error is:

`Duplicate entry 'user@email.com' for key 2 query: INSERT INTO users (name, mail, status, pass, created).....`

And I can replicate this error directly from the mysql console if i try the query there.  So this is where the issue gets weird.  the entry 'user@email.com' does not exist in the user table any where.  Thus I am perplexed at how it is generating a duplicate entry error since there is no record in the database with this email address.

here is a direct copy/paste of the mysql console..sensitive data has been changed to protect the user

`mysql> INSERT INTO users (name, mail, status, pass, created) VALUES ('username', 'user@email.com', 1, 'encryptedpassword', 1294946026);`

ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'user@email.com' for key 2

mysql> select * from users where mail='user@email.com';

Empty set (0.00 sec)

Comment: Are there any constraints/trigger/... that may do something in the background?

Comment: Can you post the table definition?

Comment: And the version of MySQL that is used? It could be a bug that is fixed in recent versions.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the [user_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_save/7) function.

For example for news users:

```
$user = user_save( null, array( 'name' => 'the name' , 'mail' => 'the user mail'));
```

Answer (score 0):

- Export the table and recreate it locally and try the insert again.
- Maybe there's an encoding issue? Try search for all users with the same domain to see if there are similar entries.
- Use the Devel module's query table to see what's actually happening within Drupal as well.